# keeping count of new items

Tags: jquery, counting

here is my scenario I have a nested sortable tree simplified looks like this

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
  <html>
   <head>
    <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <ul>
     <li id="item_123" name="123">
      <fieldset class="additem">
       <input type="text" name="title" value="">
      </fieldset>
      <ul>
       <li id="item_253" name="253">
        <fieldset class="remove additem">
          <input type="text" name="title" value="">
        </fieldset>
       </li>
       <li id="item_252" name="252">
        <fieldset class="remove additem">
          <input type="text" name="title" value="">
        </fieldset>
       </li>
       <li id="item_250" name="250">
        <fieldset class="remove additem">
          <input type="text" name="title" value="">
        </fieldset>
       </li>
       <li id="item_247" name="247">
        <fieldset class="remove additem">
          <input type="text" name="title" value="">
        </fieldset>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </body>
  </html>
```

now where the fieldset has an additem class I want to add new items to the tree that will look like all the other items in the tree and I can do that no problem

all i do is add alittle jquery that adds a button and attach a click event to it.

and I have most of my code here

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('<p class="add">Add <img src="/add.png" alt="up.png" /></p>').click(function() {
   add_item(this);
  }).prependTo("fieldset.additem");
 }

 function add_item(btn){
  var li ='
   <li id="item_new'+ X+'" name="new"'+ X+'>'+
    '<fieldset class="remove additem">'+
      '<input type="text" name="title" value="">'+
    '</fieldset>'+
   '</li>';

  if(!$(btn).parent().next('ul').length) {
   $(btn).parents("li:first").append("<ul>"+li+"</ul>");
  }else {
   $(btn).parent().next("ul").prepend(li);
  }
 }
```

notice in the above code i call a variable X that needs to be a number so that the new Items can be unique so that is what I'm looking for how to keep track of all the new items I put in to my tree

any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**
I mentioned that I using an x variable seems sloppy  but I would also like to mod this function down the road so that I can us it to add all kinds different items so I ues new+ x or old + x

Comment: as side note I could define a global variable of x= 0 in document ready but that just seems lazy and wrong

Comment: Nothing wrong with using an X variable inside the document.ready function. It's confined to that particular callback function and thus not global (can't be reached outside of the function)

Comment: how would that not be global ? if I define x in document ready it will be seen by all my functions

Answer (score 0):

About the discussion of global variables. I see now that I read your code wrong and my answer was only directed at your comment, so it came out out of context.

This is what i meant by `x` not being global if it is defined inside `document.ready`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var global = "this is global";

$(document).ready( function() {
    var notGlobal = "this is confined to the callback function of document.ready()";
    alert(global + "\n" + notGlobal)
});

//Now we're back to the global scope. "notGlobal" is not reachable from here
//This will give an error, as "notGlobal" isn't defined in this scope
alert(global + "\n" + notGlobal);

</script>
```

**The answer to your question**

In your provided jQuery code, it's true that x would need to be global, since `add_item` is defined outside of `document.ready`. Here's one solution. Put the definition of `X` and `add_item` inside of `document.ready`. That way you don't need anything in the global scope (although since `add_item` takes an `X` parameter, it doesn't need to be in the same place as the declaration of `X`)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var X = 0;

    $('<p class="add">Add <img src="/add.png" alt="up.png" /></p>')
    .click(function() {
        add_item(this,X);
        X++
    })
    .prependTo("fieldset.additem");

    function add_item(btn,X){
        var li = ''+
        '<li id="item_new'+ X+'" name="new'+ X+'">'+
            '<fieldset class="remove additem">'+
                '<input type="text" name="title" value="">'+
            '</fieldset>'+
        '</li>';

        if(!$(btn).parent().next('ul').length) {
            $(btn).parents("li:first").append("<ul>"+li+"</ul>");
        }else {
            $(btn).parent().next("ul").prepend(li);
        }
    }
});
```